# Expressão equivalente a "último aviso" mas sem conotação pejorativa

Tags: expressões, expressões-equivalentes

Estou à procura duma expressão para substituir "último aviso".
Se eu formular uma frase tal como

> ... este é o último aviso.

Parece que estou a fazer um ultimato a alguém, e que a pessoa a que me dirijo vai sofrer represálias. Isto porque "último aviso" é usado em frases como:

> João, larga já o telemóvel. Este é o último aviso!

Porém, há frases em que esta conotação não é desejada:

> Voce tem um voo amanhã às 11:00h. Este é o último aviso.

Quais são as vossas sugestões?

---

Estou a referir-me a ultimato segundo a primeira definição do [priberam](https://priberam.pt/dlpo/ultimato):

> 1. Últimas condições que um Estado apresenta a outro, e cuja não aceitação terá como resultado o início de hostilidades.

É claro que em última instância o último aviso (dito por outras palavras) continua a ser um ultimato segundo a segunda definição

> 2. Decisão final e irrevogável; última palavra.

Ou seja aquilo que quero mesmo é encontrar uma forma mais suave de informar que a pessoa não será mais avisada.

Comment: No caso específico do vôo, as companhias aéreas costumam usar "última chamada":  Esta é a última chamada para o vôo 123

Comment: @Hugo. Certo mas tenha em atenção que o meu exemplo é diferente. Pode considerar que a frase que eu dei como exemplo aparece na sua caixa de correio no dia anterior ao voo.

Comment: Como esta expressão pode ser algo distinto de um ultimato? É um aviso, e está indicando que será final. Pode-se fazer considerações sobre o tom da mensagem (certamente válidas), mas tenho dificuldades em enxergar como um "último aviso" pode deixar de ser um ultimato. Talvez um "você não receberá mais avisos como este" seja o que está procurando, mas, ao meu ver, continua sendo, essencialmente, um ultimato.

Comment: @RamonMelo Espero que o edit ajude. Mas básicamente voce já respondeu. com `você não receberá mais avisos como este`

Comment: Ah, se soubesse, teria postado como resposta. Afinal, o comentário era uma pergunta genuína, não estava tentando ser _espertinho_. Tenho uma coleção destas frases, que uso quando meus clientes perdem prazos.

Comment: Ultimato usado para quando é uma advertência.

Comment: Obrigado pela contribuição. Achei interessante a ressalva "No Português Europeu". É bom sermos irmãos de "Além-Mar". Abrs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Algumas sugestões:

- *você não receberá mais avisos como este*

> Você tem um voo amanhã às 11:00h , e não receberá mais avisos como este.

- *última notificação* (tem um tom mais leve que "aviso")

> Você tem um voo amanhã às 11:00h. Esta é a última notificação.

- *nosso último contato*

> Você tem um voo amanhã às 11:00h. Este foi [o] nosso último contato.

<sup>OBS: No português europeu, não se usa artigo antes de pronome possessivo.</sup>

- *não conversaremos/não nos falaremos/não nos comunicaremos novamente* (situacional)

> Você tem um voo amanhã às 11:00h. Não nos falaremos novamente até lá.

<sup>OBS: Esta opção soa mais rude que as anteriores. *não teremos como nos falar novamente até lá* tem um tom mais suave.</sup>

Comment: `Não nos falaremos novamente até lá` parece um bocado rude. Mas gostei das outras

Comment: @BrunoCosta Isto é porque você não conhece meus clientes! haha

Comment: @BrunoCosta Mas, de fato, tem um tom menos polido que os anteriores, por isso a chamei de "situacional".

Comment: Para não parecer rude poderia ser: `Provavelmente, não nos falaremos novamente até lá`. Dar certeza em uma frase negativa por parecer um pouco rude sem querer, depende do contexto claro :)

Comment: Ramon, no português **usa-se** artigo antes do pronome possessivo; na tua frase é basicamente obrigatório.